# SSAS: How to tell where a tabular cube process has failed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas, cube

After modifying a cube, I tried to process it, but it ended up failing returning the Following error message:

```
Echec de l'exécution de XMLA. Erreur retournée : « Cannot order ''[] by [] because at least one value in [] has multiple distinct values in []. For example, you can sort [City] by [Region] because there is only one region for each city, but you cannot sort [Region] by [City] because there are multiple cities for each region.
```

It looks to me like there are duplicates in a table, but since I'm relatively new to SSAS, I Don't know how to tell where the processing fails.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error whenever i have a column sort order set to another column (like month names sorted by their numbers), but it might be something else as well that's causing the issue.

Maybe you could process the cube table-by-table to find where the issue comes from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/process-database-table-or-partition-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#bkmk_process_table